# Google TV is not playing via https but can play http

Tags: google-tv

When I use a VideoView on Google TV 3.2 with a url like http://example.com/video.mp4 the video plays, but if I change the url to https://example.com/video.mp4 the VideoView pops up a message saying "Sorry, this video cannot be played."

Is there something special I need to do on Google TV to play the videos via https?

This is how I'm playing the video:

```
String mPath = "https://example.com/video.mp4";
mVideoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mPath));
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

Comment: please share the video URL that you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the server you are trying to stream from supports https.